# Why can an Icon be set as a Cursor and is that okay?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm working on updating an old clients software. One of their requirements is to make the cursor on their software (a custom cursor) NOT change if the computers Ease of Access settings is set to have an increased Mouse Pointer Size.

I stumbled upon a way to do this using LoadImage with the IMAGE_ICON type. If the type is set to IMAGE_ICON and the resource is of type ".ico" the cursor will NOT change size even though the rest of the system has an increased mouse pointer size (for example x12). However, if the type is set to IMAGE_CURSOR (thus loading a ".cur" resource) it DOES resize based on the users Ease of Access settings.

My question is, is it okay to use an Icon as a cursor? Why does it work as IMAGE_ICON, but not IMAGE_CURSOR? Is there a way to make this work with IMAGE_CURSOR that I'm missing?

Here is an example of the code, please note that ICON_CUSTOMCURSOR is a resource that was added to the project.

```
   HANDLE image_handle = LoadImage(GetModuleHandle("SomeModule.dll"), MAKEINTRESOURCE(ICON_CUSTOMCURSOR), IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, NULL);
   if (image_handle != NULL)
   {
      HCURSOR hCursor = (HCURSOR)image_handle;
      if (hCursor)
      {
         SetCursor(hCursor);
      }
   }
```

Comment: `HICON` and `HCURSOR` are "polymorphic" on Windows, in that they share a common implementation under the hood, and thus are basically interchangable in many icon/cursor APIs, they differ only in usage. One API that does behave different is `GetIconInfo()`, which returns more details for a cursor than an icon.

Comment: @RemyLebeau So then why do they act differently? IMAGE_ICON doesn't scale the cursor when a user adjusts their Ease of Access settings to have a scaled mouse pointer, but IMAGE_CURSOR does.... Also it seems that IMAGE_ICON doesn't position the image in the same spot as IMAGE_CURSOR (it seems to be a bit above where the actual cursor is...). Do you know how to fix the positioning?

Comment: I don't know why a cursor is scaled but an icon is not. But look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setthreadcursorcreationscaling and also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/815036/windows-cursor-size.html As for the positioning, cursors have a Hotspot which specifies an offset relative to the mouse, and that offset can be anywhere within the cursor. Icons do not have that feature, their offset is always in their center.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Creating an Icon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-icons#creating-an-icon) and [Creating a Cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-cursors#creating-a-cursor), *HCURSOR* contains some working information which include hotspot coordinate, possible scale setting based on Ease of Access settings, etc.
And according to [ICONINFOEXW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-iconinfoexw#members), *the coordinate of an icon is always in the center of the icon, and this member is ignored*.

Comment: I don't see any mention of a "possible scale setting" on the Creating a Cursor page. Is there anyway to disable this for a cursor?

Comment: Windows doesn't expose all cursor setting including the feature. You cannot utilize this for a cursor.